# How do I use other port to connect with Remote SSH VS Code extention

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I discover [Visual Studio Code Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack). I wanted to try it, but my remote is on a 2222 port.

I can correctly connect with Putty and my port 2222, same on my Linux laptop with ssh command.

What is the correct config to use Code Remote via SSH with other port ?

Thanks

```sh
Host my-remote-connection
    HostName mydomain.name
    User myusername
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `Port` to your config like:

```sh
Host my-remote-connection
    HostName mydomain.name
    User myusername
    Port 2222
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this.

Comment: One issue with that if you try and ssh from the command line it won't connect to ssh listening on port 22 and means ones can't ssh in from the terminal. Any other option on how to set this up?